# A website with a large tree-structure diagram

Tags: website-design, interface-design, critique, design-principles, information-design

I have a (personal) project that involves a tree-structure diagram (i.e. hierarchy chart) containing about 450 articles (or whatever the different parts are called) each with about a paragraph or two of text. This needs to be made into a website.

The trouble is I have no idea how it could possibly be done (I'm struggling with the concept of the website), so that all that information could be presented and accessed adequately and easily.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever tree you'll be making, nobody's going to flick through 450 links of equal weight. You need to create some structure and break down this volume into smaller sections, groups, etc:

- create a search box at the top similar to what google shows on their homepage. then under that..
- categorize: create 8-10-12 categories, list the categories, article count per category, and under each category list a few articles (latest 5, or most viewed 3, most relevant 3, etc)
- assign tags to each article and create a tag cloud: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags